# Best way to modify large CSS code / redesign a website (about 850 lines of code)

Tags: css

I want to redesign a website and I am wondering what is the best way to do that. Some people already recommended:

1) breaking the code into smaller pieces by using a CSS editor (which one?). 
2) getting rid of all the ids and classes from the xhtml and starting building the site from there (with help of Firebug or Chrome Webmaster Tools to assign rules to certain parts of the website etc)

I am just not sure how to approach that. I know CSS and (X)HTML pretty good, but I have never done a major redesign like this. It is video tube script by the way.

Thank you in advance for any info.

Answer (score 3):

You can keep everything as is, but add a new style sheet link. This new link could be included as an @import or stylesheet link.

The stylesheet would override any previous rules, and since you have a script, if the script gets updated, you just would  update the original source, while all your custom CSS changes would be in a new file.

The html code can remain as is. With positioning your elements you could make a lot of changes that looked like you recoded the website, without having to touch the html.

Comment: Just make sure you don't overdo it by having a ton of @import or different CSS files. Each file you link to (or import) takes more time to load, so keep that in mind.

Comment: Keep in mind that @import declarations must be made at the beginning of a stylesheet document. Also that whatever is under the external files is getting loaded lastly. So it is not always necessary to include '!important:' to every rule, but is to be included if it's absolutely certain.